# Rails associations – How would you apply this user association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, associations

I've been struggling to achieve the following...

1. User has many Contacts
2. Contacts belong to an Owner, which is a User
3. Creating a Contact isn't limited to just a User (Ex. A Contact can be created by a non user who submits a form, as well as by a User who adds a new contact while logged in).

Currently, when I create a contact as a user, I keep getting nil for the owner_id and user_id on a Contact.

Below is what I have so far... are there any obvious mistakes I'm making that have quick solutions to them?

**Models**

Contact Model:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :user
  validates :email, :presence => {:message => 'Email cannot be blank'}
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   has_many :leadhooks
   has_many :contacts, :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
 # validates_formatting_of :website, using: :url
 # validates_formatting_of :phone, using: :us_phone
end
```

**Controller**

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < InheritedResources::Base
before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @contacts = @user.contacts.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
    else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
  end

 def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @contact.update(contact_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
     else
       format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

 def destroy
   @contact.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contacts_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
   end
 end

 private

   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :user_id, :email, :owner_id)
  end
 end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "contacts", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "email"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "owner_id"
end

add_index "contacts", ["owner_id"], name: "index_contacts_on_owner_id", using: :btree
add_index "contacts", ["user_id"], name: "index_contacts_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

I've been following the answer given here...

[How would you model contact list with self-reference and category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548195/how-would-you-model-contact-list-with-self-reference-and-category)

But, don't know why the user_id and owner_id aren't being applied to a Contact and how to not restrict the creation of Contacts to just Users (Ex. Allowing a Contact to be created through a form submit by a non user on a web page)

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of different concerns. Addressing the first one:

*1. "But, don't know why the user_id and owner_id aren't being applied to a Contact"*

It doesn't look like you're building the association in your controller. Try something like this:

```
# controller
def new
  @user = params[:user_id] # or @user = current_user, but you need to get a user
  @contact = @user.contacts.build
end

def create
  @user = params[:user_id] # or @user = current_user, but you need to get a user
  @contact = @user.contacts.build(contact_params)
  ...
end
```

*2. "how to not restrict the creation of Contacts to just Users (Ex. Allowing a Contact to be created through a form submit by a non user on a web page)"*

If I understand correctly, contacts are people, the way a student might have multiple emergency contacts stored on file at their school. If that's true, what you're asking for here doesn't make sense. You will always want to restrict the creation of contacts to a user. Think of it this way: You will only ever care about contacts in the context of *whose* contact it is, so it needs an owner. Imagine a box full of emergency contacts in a school, with no student names on the cards (I may be dating myself here...) What good are those cards?

If you really want it to be nil, you will have to allow for nil in your controller when you are creating the new instance of Contact. Something like:

```
@contact = Contact.new(user: current_user) # will return nil if empty
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @steel for the response.

I was able to get the user_id applied to new contacts by editing the "def create" in the controller.

Regarding the second challenge, my mistake for not making it clear. 

I do want every contact to belong to a User. However, I want to allow website visitors to be able to add themselves as new contacts for a user (I.e. email subscriber signs up for a User's newsletter via web form). 

In the controller, how do we not block a website visitor from becoming a contact for a User?

As of now, only logged in Users can fill out the form and create a new contact.

Comment: Ah, that's different. Rails never sets permissions for you, so whatever is blocking visitors from creating a contact record is something you've added, such as a Devise callback. So to not block the visitor you just have to undo whatever it is you've added (maybe skipping the Devise callbacks for that method, for example). What error message do you get if a visitor submits a form? If you can, please post that error's stack trace's first five or so lines.